# Lightbox 2.7.1 when you click the link the white page pops up and loads forever

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, lightbox2

I have never used lightbox before and i have downloaded and followed the instructions on the light box page, right now im just trying to load 1 image to test it our before go further with it but i am having trouble finding info on the current version let alon any of the available versions.

when i click on the link for the image i get the white pop up and loads forever.

Comment: Please attach relevant parts of your code in your answer. In this format it's likely to be downvoted or closed.

Comment: I think their css is conflicting with my css when i make a new page with just the lightbox code it works but when i add my css it falls apart. I found another similar script called fancybox which does the same thing but without css and works fine.